# Calculating P(A>B), where A and B are normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

In the problem we have that $A \sim N(7, 11/60)$ and $B \sim N(7.3, 7/20)$ and the question is what is the probability that $A$ gives a higher value that $B.$ Since the textbook we have for the course doesn't include information about this type of question, I figured that it might just required to do manipulation with the normal law formula. So I came up with this :

\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{\frac{11}{60}\sqrt{2\pi}} 
 \exp\{-0.5
  \frac{t-7}{\frac{11}{60}}^2
 \}\Big)
 \Big(\int_{-\infty}^{t}\frac{1}{\frac{7}{20}\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\{
  -0.5\frac{x-7.3}{\frac{7}{20}}^2
 \}dx\Big) dt
\end{equation*}

What I thought could be a way to solve this was by multiplying the probability to get a lower value of $B$ (right part of the integral) by the probability of $A$ (left part of the integral) for each value of $A.$ In theory this might work, but I'm unable to actually calculate this with either my calculator or Wolfram Alpha. Is there something I'm overlooking in this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way of solving this problem *for the case when $A$ and $B$ are* **jointly normal**, is to use the fact that $A-B$ is also a normal random variable with mean equal to $E[A] -E[B]$ and variance equal to $\text{var}(A) + \text{var}(B) - 2\cdot\text{cov}(A,B)$.  So then the question simplifies to

> What is the probability than a normal random variable with given mean and variance is greater than $0$?

the answer to which can be obtained from tables of the standard normal distribution function.  You don't say anything about whether $A$ and $B$ are **jointly normal**
or not, though your approach seems to indicate that you are treating them as *independent* normal random variables (which happen to be jointly normal).  Note that this approach *cannot* be used when $A$ and $B$ are normal but *not jointly normal* random variables because in this case $A-B$ is not a normal random variable.

Comment: How is it possible for two Normal RVs not to be jointly Normal?

Comment: @Alex Excerpt from an [answer I wrote](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25919/6633) on stats.SE.  Consider two standard normal random variables. If they are _jointly normal_, then $p(x,y)$ is the bivariate normal density. As a  special case, if they are independent, then $p(x,y) = p(x)p(y)$. But they _could_ be marginally normal random variables that are **not jointly normal** with joint density $$p(x,y)=\begin{cases}2p(x)p(y),&\text{if}~x\geq 0, y\geq 0,\text{or}~x<0,y<0,\\0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ For even more possibilities, see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/6633).

Comment: OK thanks, I'll have a look at this.