# How to integrate the difference between the CDFs of two normal distributions

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution

I have two normal distributions A and B. I am trying to write a program that will take mean(A), stddev(A), mean(B), stddev(B) and output the result of the following equation:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} CDF_A(x) - CDF_B(x)\,dx 
$$
Is there some closed-form equation to calculate this? If not, is there a nice way to break it down to get a good approximation?

I could just iterate over some range of x values and sum up the differences over a small delta around x, but I'd prefer a non linear time solution.

Comment: 1.) Why are you integrating CDFs? 2.) Integrals are a linear operator, so just separately integrate the CDF of distribution A and distrubution B: $\int f-g\ dx = \int f\ dx - \int g\ dx$.

Comment: Given two normal PDFs, I'm trying to find the probability that if you take one sample from A and one sample from B, the value from A will be smaller the value from B. Thought I might be able to do this by looking at summing over CDFs, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @arkamis No, the integrals $\int f\,\mathrm dx$ and $\int g\,\mathrm dx$ are divergent and so their difference is undefined.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Ah, good point, since it's to infinity. As the answers suggest, CDFs are not what you want to integrate. CDFs are the integral of PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, you need to derive $W=X_1-X_2$ and then find $P(W<0$. See also [here](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/15666-Difference-of-two-Gaussian-RV-s)

Comment: Ok so this makes it sound easy: I create a new normal distribution Z where mean(Z) = mean(A)-mean(B) and stddev(Z) = sqrt(stddev(A)^2+stddev(B)^2). Then I can just take the CDF_Z(0). Does that equation work for all normally distributed PDFs, or does that business with "jointly normal" distributions change things?

Comment: You didn't mention anything about joint distribution. This approach works for independent normal RVs

Answer (score 0):

To find what you are looking for (as you say in your comments), look at the answers
to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214560/15941).

Comment: I don't understand what he means when he says A and B must be "jointly normal". Do you think either you could explain it or point to a reference explaining what exactly that means?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ being _jointly normal_ implies that $A$ and $B$ are normal random variables. The converse is not true except in the special case when $A$ and $B$ are _independent_ (normal) random variables, which is what you implicitly assumed in your comment on Alex's answer. For examples of normal random variables that are not jointly normal, see [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/6633) on stats.SE

Answer (score 0):

First you should know that for normal random variables :
$$ CDF(x) = \frac12 (1+erf(\frac{x-\mu}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2}}))
$$
where
$$ erf(x)= \frac2{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt
$$
Therefore: 
$$\large {I= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}CDF_A(x)-CDF_B(x)dx =\frac1{\sqrt \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \int_{\frac{x-\mu_B}{\sqrt{2\sigma_B^2}}}^{\frac{x-\mu_A}{\sqrt{2\sigma_B^2}}} e^{-t^2}dt dx}
$$
After changing variables we would have :
$$I = \mu_B - \mu_A
$$

Comment: can you elaborate on that last step please